# OpenSSL CocoaPod iOS with Bitcode?

Tags: ios, openssl, cocoapods, bitcode

Is there an OpenSSL cocoapod that works with bitcode enabled? Previously I was using the `pod 'OpenSSL'`, but I want to have bitcode in my app. Is there any way to do this, or must I build OpenSSL by myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can answer this question, as I figured out how to do it. Since there is no official CocoaPod, you will have to use a build script to build it yourself. Here is the build script that I used:
https://gist.github.com/felix-schwarz/c61c0f7d9ab60f53ebb0

This build script will generate two folders for you, one called `lib` and another called `include`. Go to your project settings and go to `Build Phases`. Open the section called `Link Binary With Libraries`. Then, open the `lib` folder and drag `libcrypto_iOS.a` and `libssl_iOS.a` into the `Link Binary With Libraries` section.

Next, go to `Build Settings`. Under the `Search Paths` section, Go to `Header Search Paths`, double click the field, which will open another box. In there, drag the include folder. Also make sure that the `Library Search Paths` have the `lib` folder.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is an `openssl-ios-bitcode` pod now, currently with OpenSSL 1.0.212.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't encounter any pod for openSSL with bitcode, but if you build it yourself, it is possible.
As you mentioned yourself, you can use OpenSSL-for-iOS (https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone)
and just run ./build-libssl.sh

Then you will see some libraries with the openSSL output.
See how it has been linked and used in the OpenSSL-for-iOS example project, and try to do the same in your project.