# XCode: Where are run script generated folders located?

Tags: ios, xcode, bash

I am trying to run the openssl script (as instructed by this answer: [OpenSSL CocoaPod iOS with Bitcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472985/openssl-cocoapod-ios-with-bitcode)) and adding the built folders to my libaries. However when I run this script with the shell :'/bin/bash' I cannot locate the folder that the lib and include files that should be generated are located.

Answer (score 0):

As per script, it will generate in the same folder where you are running the script.